# Multithreaded socket in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to edit code I wrote earlier from creating a client and server socket, allowing the client to send a message to the server and the server responds with "I got it.." + Message. This works well but the next steps are what I am having issues with.

I want to be able to continuously send messages until the client says "Exit", and support multiple clients.

The code I have that works for a one on one client/server communication:

Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n; // return value for the read() and write() calls

    // gcc server.c -o server
    // ./server 8080
    // Pass in Port # or pass error
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    // Error if Socket Call fails
    if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); // Set all values in a buffer to zero, args: pointer to buffer, size of buffer, sets serv_addr ot zero
    portno = atoi(argv[1]); // Port number listens for connections
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    // Binds socket to an address
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
            error("ERROR on binding");

    // Listens to the socket for connections
    listen(sockfd,5);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR on accept");

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);


    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0; 
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>  



void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[256];
    // gcc client.c -o client
    // ./client localhost 8080
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    // Error Connecting to the server
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

My thoughts were for the server file have a while loop:

```
while(buffer != "EXIT"){
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);


    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
}
```

but it only does one interaction between one client and server.

Comment: If you want to handle multiple clients, you need either mulitple server threads, or select or poll to manage input from multiple fds simultaneously in one thread.

Comment: When people refer to multithread servers, they generally mean to say a server that can feed many clients "at the same time" for which we need work from different processors. Otherwise its like a queue, you serve one client and then give turn to next one.

Comment: Although in your question, you can't accept more than one client. `listen()` takes a backlog argument to specify how many clients can wait in a queue if server is busy. When `accept()` is called, client is removed from the queue and server has its info and can start contacting it. In your server, your are only calling `accept()` once which is why you can't accept more than one client. You need to put that in a loop to keep accepting clients.

Comment: When you do all this is a loop, you will be able to work with clients one by one. The main intention of multithreaded server is to work with clients on the same time and use all the CPUs available. You can do it either by spawning new processes(see `fork()`) for each client or new threads for each client(see `pthread`).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a multi threaded application. The basic problem which I can see here is your server is not ready to accept multiple client at the same time. While loop is only going to process the read and write one by one.

The basic logic which needs to be implemented is :

1.) Accept the new connection request using 'accept' function.

2.) Create a new thread(using pthread_create) to read and write to the same connection request. and simultaneously get ready for the new connection request from 'accept' function.

3.) Follow step 1 and 2 to keep the flow of sending and receiving until you get 'EXIT'.